# Changing the order of double integral

Tags: integration

Is there a general way to change the order of any double integral, no matter what are the boundaries or the function? I know you can sketch the function and see what are the boundaries and then change the limits, but is there an algebraic way to do it?
I've seen on MSE many similar questions to mine, and the answer was either Iverson Brackets, solving inequalities( though I have some doubts about it) or Heaviside Function(the latter is more used in the questions I've seen).
But the problem was in a comment where I've read that if the limits are complex then it is better to sketch, but I don't want to sketch because it's time consuming (especially in exams) and sometimes it's hard to draw.
So isn't there a general advanced way to switch integrals algebraicly without sketching? It seems unbelievable that no one could came with a way to do this.

Comment: You can google Fubini's theorem.

Comment: Just don't put boundaries and instead use the indicator function.

Comment: Sketching is just a way to get a feel for how the functions involved behave. It is not strictly necessary - you would be able to write the boundaries of the integral with changed order simply by studying the properties of the involved functions. You should pick one simple example and see if you can do the changing of the order without any drawing. (You can start by drawing and then see what properties of the graph you actually used, and then see how you would discover those properties without the graph). That said, sketching is a great aid and is likely to help produce a faster solution.

Comment: To change the order of an *iterated integral* (a double integral is properly a single integration over area, not two linear integrations in different directions) requires determining the new upper and lower limits in each direction. These upper and lower limits *are* a set of inequalities, so swapping them means solving the set for the other variable first. I.e. exchanging the order of integration means solving a set of inequalities. There is no way around that.

Comment: Iverson Brackets and Heaviside/Indicator functions are notations that are useful *when you don't have to actually perform the calculation*. That is, when what you are after is some theoretic relationship, not actual numbers. They hide the messy boundaries when you actually are not interested in them, because you have some other purpose. But when you need to actually come up with a value, where those boundaries are is critical, and you would still have to deal with them with these notations. There is nothing gained.